# Adding an UIImageView to the Subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, subview

I got following code:

```
func addObject(object: UIImageView)
{
    view.addSubview(object)
}
```

and in another class I got this code:

```
func loadPlayground(width: CGFloat)
{

    let playerX =  screenWidth / fieldWidth * 2
    let playerY =  screenHight / fieldWidth * 2
    let player1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(playerX, playerY, width, width))
    player1.image = player
    ViewController().addObject(player1)
    print(playerX)
```

and the variable player is:

```
let player = UIImage(named: "Player.png")
```

Now my problem. My error code is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x114fbc).

It appears in the line where I'm trying to add the object to the Subview inside the class addObject. I also got the console output of the function various times. That let me conclude that the function got started often and stops after a time. Hopefully you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are creating a new instance of `ViewController` everytime for adding the image view.

```
ViewController().addObject(player1)
```

So in the `addObject` method the `view` will be `nil` always, because it is not loaded yet.

For fixing this issue, you want to re-use the actual `ViewController` that is loaded currently or add the image view to the view after it is loaded.

Comment: What would be a possible solution. I got two classes and thats the only way I know to access them.

Comment: @LukasKöhl: What is the relation between both ? How you displayed the second view controller ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that ViewController() is the name of the second class. I already got things displayed on the view controller in the same class as the addObject function is in.

Comment: I think you need something like `self.addObject(player1)`

Comment: It still won't work... And its also hard to describe  my problem because I'm not very good in programming.